# Shaivism influences on Bhagavad Geeta

Tags: bhagavad-gita, identification-request, shaivism, reference-request, kashmiri-shaivism

Are there editions of the Bhagavad Geeta or inside the Bhagavad Geeta itself are there shlokas which proves to have received influences from Shaivism or Kashmirian Shaivism ancient scriptures?

Answer (score 2):

There is one version of Bhagwat Gita as per Shaiva point of view from the last guru in the lineage of Kashmiri Shaivism, Swami Lakshmanjoo Maharaj. Name of the book is **"Bhagwat Gita in the light of Kashmiri Shaivism".**

One can buy the book from their official site. Here is link to that: https://www.universalshaivafellowship.org/store/bhagavad-gita-in-the-light-of-kashmir-shaivism-27-dvd-video.html